# How to add watermark text in the bottom left of my image using Imageresizer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I've wrote a little bit code for resizing an image.image is resized but i want to add watermark on it. I've wrote these code but i didn't see any effect on my image.

**update :** I need after that my image is resized watermark add on it.

```
var path = Server.MapPath("/UploadFiles/Images/GoodGallery/");
 versions.Add("_small", "maxwidth=270&maxheight=180&format=jpg");
 versions.Add("_large", "maxwidth=600&maxheight=400&format=jpg");

 foreach (var suffix in versions.Keys)
 {
     file.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
     ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(file, path + file.FileName + suffix, new Instructions(versions[suffix]), false, true));
     ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, path + file.FileName, new ResizeSettings("watermark=test2"));
 }
```

==============

```
 <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="Watermark" />
    </plugins>
    <watermarks>
      <!--color="FFFFFF99"-->
      <text name="test2" text="فروشگاه سورنا"
       vertical="true" align="bottomleft"  />
    </watermarks>
  </resizer>
```

Comment: Reset the stream to byte 0 before building again. Remember to combine the resize and watermark commands.

Comment: @NathanaelJones,please you write correct code . I coudn't do it.